# Magento - How to hide categories and sub-categories with no products

Tags: php, magento, navigation, magento-1.7, categories

I'm trying to hide all the categories and sub-categories from frontend with no active products in magento but I don't want to use admin backend to do it manually. I want to display only those categories in top level navigation which have their product count greater than zero. I have tried previous solutions given on the below links:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/80/6099

& Josh Prattski's blog post,

http://prattski.com/2011/10/06/magento-module-hide-empty-categories/

None of the solutions are working for me and there's no way for me to know what am I doing wrong. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: You might find this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822997/remove-empty-categories-from-magento-menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to create your own template category tree and implemnt condition to the function which render category tree:

```
foreach ($children as $child) {
    if ($child->getIsActive() && $this->_hasProducts($child->entity_id)) {
        $activeChildren[] = $child;
    }
}
```

Function _hasProducts:

```
    protected function _hasProducts($category_id) {
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
        ->getProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('entity_id')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
    return ( $products->count() > 0 )  ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this solution and still the problem persists.

Comment: it works for me months ago, i found the source which i first used, maybe it helps http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36/hide-categories-with-no-active-products

Answer (score 2):

You can execute following sql to disable all categories without products.

```
UPDATE `catalog_category_entity_int` AS `status`
INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `attr` ON `attr`.`attribute_code` = 'is_active'
AND `attr`.`entity_type_id` = 3
AND `status`.`attribute_id` = `attr`.`attribute_id`
SET `status`.`value` = IF((SELECT COUNT(`index`.`product_id`)
    FROM `catalog_category_product_index` AS `index`
    WHERE `index`.`category_id` = `status`.`entity_id` GROUP BY `index`.`category_id`) > 0, 1, 0)
WHERE `status`.`store_id` = 0
```

More details you can find here http://quicktips.ru/all/hide-all-categories-without-products-and-show-categories-with-pr/

Answer (score 0):

I should preface all of this with the below applies to magento 2.3, possibly 2.x and up... I am working on 2.3 at the moment...

I am still trying to grapple with repositories and factories, all the code above or that i can find regarding this does not use either repositories or factories, and this seems to still be an issue even in magento 2.3 so what I did was two lines in mysql you may have to modify if you have more than one store...  first it is much easier to just disable all categories and then enable any category that has any products, than the other way around, so one line to disable all categories in tree on frontend in mysql shell or phpmyadmin...

```
update catalog_category_entity_int set catalog_category_entity_int.value = 0 where catalog_category_entity_int.store_id = 0 and catalog_category_entity_int.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from  eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'include_in_menu') or catalog_category_entity_int.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from  eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'is_active');
```

then turn active and include in menu any categories that have any products in stock with

```
update catalog_category_entity_int left join catalog_category_product on catalog_category_product.category_id = catalog_category_entity_int.entity_id left join cataloginventory_stock_item on cataloginventory_stock_item.product_id = catalog_category_product.product_id set catalog_category_entity_int.value = 1 where catalog_category_entity_int.store_id = 0 and cataloginventory_stock_item.qty > 0 and catalog_category_entity_int.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from  eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'include_in_menu') or cataloginventory_stock_item.qty > 0 and catalog_category_entity_int.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from  eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'is_active');
```

there is an extension somewhere that has not been updated for the newer magento, that someone experienced issues with from this stackexchange here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/36/hide-categories-with-no-active-products

two lines is simple and could even be made into a procedure.

this by no means should be a final solution, but should get the job done until  this sort of thing is built into the core... one shouldn't have to code an extension for something simple like this...

Comment: Could be done as a cron or as part of the catalog category indexer using queries as shown on here.