# Magento Sort categories by product count

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am in need of some assistance. I am using Magento 1.8.1 and I need to display subcategories in the navigation menu in descending order of their product count.

I have no idea on how to approach the subject, so any hint or possible solution would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You mean Root > Sub-Category > Sub category(Product Count) or Root > Sub-Category(Product Count) ?

Comment: The first one, Root > Sub-Category > Sub category(Product Count)

Comment: You can drag/drop the sub-categories form your admin end to arrange them in descending order of their product count. The same order will be reflected on your front end

Comment: I know I can do it manually in the admin interface, but I wanted a programatical solution in order to create the order automatically.

Comment: I had a related requirement but to exclude empty categories from the menu. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822997/remove-empty-categories-from-magento-menu explains how I did it. Sorting your entries will be harder but this might give you a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code once. Change your category ID.

```
<?php
    $cats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(3)->getChildrenCategories();
?>
 <ul>   
    <?php
    $resourcearray = array();
    foreach($cats as $category): 
    $proCnt = $category->getProductCount();
    $proName = $category->getName();
    $proUrl = $category->getUrl();
    array_push($resourcearray, array('count' => $proCnt, 'name' => $proName,'url' => $proUrl));
    ?>
    <?php endforeach; 
    ksort($resourcearray);
    ?>
    <?php foreach($resourcearray as $val): ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $val['url'] ?>"><?php echo $val['name'] ?>(<?php echo $val['count'] ?>)</a>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    </ul>
```