# Hide empty/out of stock category magento 1.9

Tags: magento, menu, hide, categories

Trying to hide a category in the top menu bar if it is empty or the products in it are out of stock. I have tried multiple solutions, none seem to work with 1.9. Thanks.

Comment: Then post your trials

Comment: Could I refer you to my question and answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822997/remove-empty-categories-from-magento-menu. This might help you.

Comment: I have already tried your solution Pedro, it didn't work for me. I also tried this http://prattski.com/2011/10/06/magento-module-hide-empty-categories/ no luck there either

Comment: Did it not work at all? I usually throw in a garbage line in the php to confirm my module is getting called (lovely white screen of death!). I then echo various variables to check further. One thing, is your main menu built by Topmenu.php? If not, my method certainly won't work (again, try some garbage or echo "Hallo World" in the core file just to be sure).