# How to hide categories which is not having any products in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am showing products categories after clicking on any Brand but i want to hide those categories which do no have any products. I am trying from last 6 hours to find the solution but no solution i have found
 here is my code below :

```
<?php

//Image Adjustment
$config = Mage::getModel('manufacturers/image_config');
$image = Mage::getModel('media/image');
$image->setConfig($config);
//Get Manfacturer Info
 $mId  = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

/****************Category Collection**********************/
$manufacturersTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('manufacturers');
        $manufacturersProductsTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('manufacturers_products');

        $sqry = "SELECT mp.product_id,mp.manufacturers_id FROM ".$manufacturersTable." m 
                INNER JOIN ".$manufacturersProductsTable." AS mp ON m.manufacturers_id = mp.manufacturers_id
                WHERE m.manufacturers_id = ".$mId;
        $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $select = $connection->query($sqry);
        $prds = $select->fetchAll();    
        $categoryIds=array();
        $i=0;
        foreach ($prds as $_manufacturer) {

             $productIds= $_manufacturer["product_id"];
                $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productIds);
             $categoryIds = array_merge($_product->getCategoryIds(), $categoryIds);

            $i++;
        }

$product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prds[0]['product_id']);

       $manufacturer = $_product["manufacturer"];
       if(empty($manufacturer))
       {
       $manufacturer = $product->getManufacturer();
       }
?>
    <?php if ($mId != 0 ) { ?>
    <?php
        $model  = Mage::getModel('manufacturers/manufacturers')->load($mId);

        $x = Mage::helper('manufacturers')->getLogoWidth();  
        $y = Mage::helper('manufacturers')->getLogoHeight(); 
        $color = Mage::helper('manufacturers')->getLogoBackgroundColor();

        if($model["m_logo"] != "") {
            $imgPath = Mage::helper('manufacturers')->getResizedUrl($model["m_logo"],$x,$y,$color); 
        } else {            
            $imageFile =  "manufacturers/files/n/i/no_image_available.jpg";
            $imgPath = Mage::helper('manufacturers')->getResizedUrl($imageFile,$x,$y,$color);
        }

    ?>
$rootCatId = 257; // haikal 257
$catids=array();
$cat='';
function getTreeCategories($parentId, $isChild){
$allCats = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active','1')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu','1')

            ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id',array('eq' => $parentId))
            ->addAttributeToSort('position');

$class = ($isChild) ? "sub-cat-list" : "cat-list";


foreach ($allCats as $category) 
{

    $html .= $category->getID().',';
    $subcats = $category->getChildren();
    if($subcats != ''){

        $html .= getTreeCategories($category->getId(), true);

    }

}

return $html;
}
$catlistHtml = getTreeCategories($rootCatId, true);
//echo $catlistHtml;
($catlistHtml=explode(',', $catlistHtml));

if(count($_GET)) {

?>
<script>
function abc()
{



window.location = window.location.href.split("?")[0];


}
</script>
<div id="whole-cat" class="whole-cat" style="display:none;">
<?php
}
else{
?>


<div id="whole-cat" class="whole-cat" style="display:block">
<?php
}

global $showleftNav;

if(!$showleftNav)
{



$o = null;

$o .= '<div class="content">';

$_columnCount = 5; 
$i = 0;
$j = 0;


foreach ($catlistHtml as $_category) {


    // if the category is not match the product categories

    if(!in_array($_category, $categoryIds))  continue; 

    $i++;

    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category);

    //$_category = $_category->load($catId);
   $imgurl=$_category->getImageUrl();

     $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getProductCount();

     if($products_count==0) continue;

   if(empty($imgurl))
   {
   $imgurl=$this->getSkinUrl('images/small_image.jpg');
   }
    if ($j++%$_columnCount==0):
        $o .= '<ul class="pro-cat">';
    endif;
    $o .= '<li id="m'.$manufacturer.'" class="categoryName row'.$i.'"><a href="'.$_category->getUrl().'?manufacturer='.$manufacturer.'"><h4>'.$_category->getName().'</h4><img src="'.$imgurl.'" ></a></li class="totalNumberOfProducts">';



    if ($j%$_columnCount==0): 
    $o .= '</ul>';
    endif;
    }



echo $o;
?>


<?php 

$showleftNav==true;

}

?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

In output i have seen that no category is hide

I have tried almost everything i have tried to get Category id by name so that i can search the category and get its id and apply filter.

[My page link](http://www.lifestylestore.com.au/bowers-n-wilkins.html)

Comment: Is there any who can solve this issue ??

Comment: This is how I did it to hide empty categories from the main menu. If not exactly what you want, it might point you in the right direction. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822997/remove-empty-categories-from-magento-menu

Answer (score 1):

Here is the details explanation about this feature:

http://prattski.com/2011/10/06/magento-module-hide-empty-categories/

Comment: This is only hiding categories??

My process is little complex i am showing brands first then categories will it work for me also??

Comment: I tried but not working for me  [My Website](http://www.lifestylestore.com.au/bowers-n-wilkins.html) here is page you can see the categories having no products are still there. . :(